# Direct URL access

Tags: php, url

Suppose, I have several pages in a project (login.php, terms.php, profile.php,
add_user.php etc.).login & terms are consecutive pages. After entering correct credential user will come to terms.php page to accept T&C which include a checkbox.
So my requirement is when a user accepts T&C then redirect to profile page and it's working fine. Now I want if user try to change URL of any different page which is related to profile section (eg.profile.php,add_user.php..... any page) without accepting T&C then it should redirect to same page i.e. terms.php. I want to restrict user to access any page without accepting T&C by direct changing the URL.[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you have to add status filed in your MySQL data base for T&C
It means that when user login in your system  that time first page is T&C when accept that page Your status is true (set 1) then go to next page . if user go to direct profile page so before going to profile page you have to check status of particular user if status is 0 then redirect to T&C page and if status is 1 then redirect to apply url..

Comment: i have already added a status and its checking true/false value

Comment: and its not only about profile page there are lots of pages so i have to check status in all the pages which is lengthy.

Comment: ya that required for all page and same process